# What is this metal part and does it fit into the fridge?

Tags: refrigerator, identify-a-tool

I finished moving a couple of days ago and noticed this metal part that apparently belongs to my fridge:

[image]

The backside of the fridge looks like this (if that is where it belongs?):

[image: fridge backside]

Does the piece belong to the fridge? and, if so, what is its purpose and where does it fit?

The fridge brand is Bosch, in case that matters.

Comment: Do all of the wheels turn freely? It might be an axle for one of them.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like one of your fridge wheels lost its rotational pin.

You should notice that the fridge does not roll well.

Replacing it will involve lifting or tilting the fridge.

That can happen if the fridge was lifted during transport.

Comment: I would have called it an axle, but that's what it is,